# Segfaults, dynamic arrays, and functions

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, dynamic-arrays

Program segfaults whenever a dynamic is initialized with a function.
Program without function:

```
int main(){
    int x, y;//axis of the matrix
    int **matrix;// the matrix
    x=2;//initilization of the x-axis
    y=2;//initilization of the y-axis
    matrix=new int*[x];
        for (int i=0; i<x; i++){
            matrix[i]=new int[y];
        }
    matrix[1][1]=1;
    cout << matrix[1][1]<< endl;
```

}

Program with function that causes segfault:

```
void setmatrix(int **matrixac, int x, int y){
    matrixac=new int*[x];
    for (int i=0; i<x; i++){
        matrixac[i]=new int[y];
    }
}


int main(){
    int x, y;//axis of the matrix
    int **matrix;// the matrix
    x=2;//initilization of the x-axis
    y=2;//initilization of the y-axis
    setmatrix(matrix, x, y);//initilization of the matrix
    matrix[1][1]=1;
    cout << matrix[1][1]<< endl;
}
```

I'm sort of new at this, so I don't know enough about segfaults to tell what the difference is. Help would be appreciated, please.

Comment: Change the function to take in a reference to the pointer. `int ** &matrixac`

Comment: That worked, Thanks. May I ask why a reference to a pointer is needed?

Comment: Because that pointer is passed by *value* in your code, so you are modifying a copy of it. Don't forget to delete those pointers, too.

Comment: because you are changing matrixac

Comment: Thanks, that helps. This problem also occurs when passing an object that uses a dynamic array, can I ask for advice on that in this question?

Comment: The best advice for you would be to spend some time with your C++ book learning the fundamentals of what pointers, references, and objects are, how they work, what it means to pass a parameter to a function by value or reference. You need to understand these key, fundamental concepts, and then all these details will become crystal clear. A full explanation of these can only be found in a good C++ book, and stackoverflow.com is not really a substitute for such a book.

Comment: I don't have a c++ book. Most are too expensive, and the online ones I've found are either incomplete, or don't cover the issues that I'm having. If you have an online c++ book that you would be willing to recommend, I would be grateful.